# Android:the app restarted with empty data

Tags: android

my problem is when i trying to restarted the app after one hours,the application opened with empty data,i beleive the the kernel remove the resources without kill the process.please help me .thx

Comment: without code snippet & logcat, its really difficult to help you.

Comment: ok,for example i use a static array list where i stored the data,but when i reopen the app,i saw an empty list view

Comment: you should not use static variables in the android apps, try to use some persisent storage, and whenever required pass the data between activities in Bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "empty data"?
 If you mean some dynamic variables, of course their state will be lost after app restart.

You should handle app close event and save data which you want, and then restore needed data back.

For example, you can handle `onPause()` method of the activity, where you want to save data and store needed data in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or file or `SQLite database`. And then restore that data in `onResume()` method.

I would recommend you to read about Android [`Apps`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components), [`Activities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) lifecycle.

UPD:

You said that you are using static `ArrayList` and store data there, of course data will be  lost after app restart. So you need to save data from `ArrayList` to `file` or `database` or use easiest solution and store it in [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Example:

```
/**
* Saving data
*/
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Here you can save your data
    // If you want to store your ArrayList, it should implement Parselable
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("STORE_KEY", yourArrayListWhichShouldImplementParcelable);
}

/**
* Restoring data
*/
@Override
public onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    yourArrayList = (YourArrayList) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("STORE_KEY");
}
```

Something like this

Comment: can i kill the app when the kernel removed the resources to free the memory?

Answer (score 0):

you have to store your data in some kind of persisent storage, i guess.
there are few options available on the android platform:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html